# How does Tensorflow Federated update model from server

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

New to Tensorflow so not sure if this is a specific question for Tensorflow Federated.

I'm studying adversarial attack on federated learning in this [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/targeted_attack/attacked_fedavg.py). I'm curious how the weights received from the server are updated at the client.

For example, here is the code for a 'benign' update:

```
@tf.function
def compute_benign_update():
  """compute benign update sent back to the server."""
  tf.nest.map_structure(lambda a, b: a.assign(b), model_weights,
                        initial_weights)

  num_examples_sum = benign_dataset.reduce(initial_state=tf.constant(0),
                                           reduce_func=reduce_fn)

  weights_delta_benign = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda a, b: a - b,
                                               model_weights.trainable,
                                               initial_weights.trainable)

  aggregated_outputs = model.report_local_outputs()
  return weights_delta_benign, aggregated_outputs, num_examples_sum
```

I can see that the initial weights received from the server are assigned to `model_weights` then `reduce_fn` is used to train on a batch of data on the local client.

```
@tf.function
def reduce_fn(num_examples_sum, batch):
  """Runs `tff.learning.Model.train_on_batch` on local client batch."""
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    output = model.forward_pass(batch)
  gradients = tape.gradient(output.loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
  return num_examples_sum + tf.shape(output.predictions)[0]
```

Inside this function training occurs and (I think) `model.trainable_variables` is updated. The part that doesn't make sense to me is how the `weights_delta_benign` is calculated:

```
weights_delta_benign = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda a, b: a - b,
                                             model_weights.trainable,
                                             initial_weights.trainable)
```

It seems that the difference between `model_weights.trainable` and `initial_weights.trainable` is used, but didn't we originally set these to be equal in the first line of the `compute_benign_update()` function? I'm assuming the `reduce_fn` alters `initial_weights` somehow but I don't see the connection between `model.trainable_variables` used in the reduce function and `initial_weights.trainable_variables`.

Thanks, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you point to, `initial_weights` is only a collection of values (`tf.Tensor` objects), and `model_weights` is a reference to the `model`'s variables (`tf.Variable` objects). We use `initial_weights` to assign the initial value to the model's variables.

Then, in the call to `optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))`, you only modify the model's variables. (`model.trainable_variables`, which refers is the same objects as `model_weights.trainable`. I acknowledge, this is a bit confusing.)

So the subsequent computation of `weights_delta_benign` is computing the difference between the model's trainable variables at the end and start of the client's training procedure.